# Installing Docker on Windows Server 2016 TP4

Tags: windows, docker, server

I want to install Docker on a physical machine with Windows Server 2016 installed. (Using the Admin-Account, not a Guest or Normal User Account)

So i tried this [guideline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_configure_host).

But the second command fails with following error:

Command: powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\Install-ContainerHost.ps1 -HyperV

```
...
Docker is already installed.
Installing ContainerImage provider...
C:\Install-ContainerHost.ps1 : Could not install ContainerImage provider
In Line:1 ...
+ C:\Install-ContainerHost.ps1 -HyperV
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException, Install-ContainerHost.ps1
```

I can't find a solution.. any Ideas?

EDIT/UPDATE:
I reinstalled the Windows Server 2016. After the first run of the script i get this error:

```
...
Downloading NSSM...
Extracting NSSM for archive...
Configuring NSSM for Docker service...
Starting Docker...
Waiting for Docker daemon...
An error occurred trying to connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
...
An error occurred trying to connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
C:\Users\Administrator\Install-ContainerHost.ps1 : Docker Daemon did not start successfully within 1 minute.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ C:\Users\Administrator\Install-ContainerHost.ps1 -HyperV
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-ContainerHost.ps1
```

In the following executions of the script i get the error in my first post.

Comment: Did you run this from an administrative prompt? Sounds like it cant write some data somewere.

Comment: Yes i do. I'm using the Admin Account and started the shell explicit as Admin.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same exact problem and the following is how and what fixed it.

If you run `Get-PSRepository` on your system I was seetign the message "WARNING: Unable to find module repositories".  Running on my Windows 10 box showed that i did have a repository setup.

I ran the following to set the same repository

```
powershell Register-PSRepository -Name "PSGallery" –SourceLocation "https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/" -InstallationPolicy Trusted
```

Everything worked a treat.

I am using the Windows Server 2016 TP5 but i think it this will solve your issue.

Comment: the command "Get-PSRepository" returns a list with one Entry: PSGallery. But the InstallationPolicy is Untrusted not Trusted. How can i change this?

Comment: @nast try `powershell Set-PSRepository -Name "PSGallery" -InstallationPolicy Trusted`

Answer (score 0):

For whoever is looking an answer in 2021
I installed docker on Windows Server 2016 using the following commands on powershell as admin

1. Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery –Force
2. Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -verbose
3. get-service docker
4. start-service docker